# Why life cycle activtity methods are not called when android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" is in manifest file

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-lifecycle, android-configchanges, onstart

I have overridden methods `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onStop()`, `onPause()` in `MainActivity`. I am using `log.d()` command to monitor when those methods are called.

When I use `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest, my overridden methods are not called. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways to handling Runtime Changes.

```
1. Retain an object during a configuration change
2. Handle the configuration change yourself
```

**1. Retain an object during a configuration change**

If you retain an object during configuration change Android restarts the running Activity and `onDestroy()` is called, followed by `onCreate()` and from there all the others: `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onStop()`, `onPause()`, etc

but if you want to handle the configuration by yourself comes the second way:

**2. Handle the configuration change by yourself**

Here if your application doesn't need to update resources during a specific configuration change and you have a performance limitation that requires you to avoid the activity restart, then you can declare that your activity handles the configuration change itself, which prevents the system from restarting your activity.

This happens when you include in your manifest [android:configChanges](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) attribute with a value that represents the configuration you want to handle.

For example:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

> Now, when one of these configurations change, **MyActivity does not
>   restart**. Instead, the MyActivity receives a call to
>   [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)). This method is passed a Configuration
>   object that specifies the new device configuration

For example, the following **onConfigurationChanged()** implementation checks the current device orientation:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

For more information you can continue reading in [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Answer (score 1):

That is because `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in manifest is instructing not to recreate activity on orientation or screen size changes.

You can override `onConfigurationChanged` method of your activity if you need to do something on orientation changes.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

If you **do want** to restart activity on orientation and screen size changes, the you have to remove `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` from your manifest.

---

Excerpt from [manifest activity element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)

```
android:configChanges
```

Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its `onConfigurationChanged()` method is called.